# File not downloading with download.file

Tags: r, curl

I'm not able to get a file to download with `download.file`.

**My code:**

```
setwd("C:/Users/James/Documents/coursera/course 3/w1"
if(!file.exists("data")) {
  dir.create("data")
}

fileUrl <- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
download.file(fileUrl, ".data/caeras.csv", method="curl")
list.files("./data")
```

**I am getting the errors below:**

> Error in download.file(fileUrl, ".data/caeras.csv", method = "curl") :
>     'curl' call had nonzero exit status
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   running command 'curl  "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"  -o ".data/caeras.csv"' had status 23

(Note: The file location works and the directory is there.)

Why is the file not downloading?

Comment: perhaps, `./data` vs `.data`? in the `download.file()` call?

Comment: Thanks, that's correct.